# How do I transform pandas pivot table to regular dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

My pandas pivot after many operations inside look like below

```
    Date      2019-12-20         2019-12-21          2019-12-22                                                     
City 
Madrid            12                 15                  12           
Valencia          15                 16                  12          
Sevilla           15                 30                  12
```

How can I convert this pivot table to a regular dataframe such as this:

```
Date             City          Value
2019-12-20       Madrid         12
2019-12-20       Valencia       15
2019-12-20       Sevilla        15
2019-12-21       Madrid         15
2019-12-21       Valencia       16
2019-12-21       Sevilla        30
2019-12-22       Madrid         12
2019-12-22       Valencia       12
2019-12-22       Sevilla        12
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This: `df.melt()`.

Comment: I could fix this but your DF is weird, can you print(df.to_dict()) it so I can create a dataframe

Comment: you could remove Date and City and then `pd.read_clipboard()` and then `rename_axis` @oppressionslayer

Comment: @ansev, ohhh, that worked, thanks ansev! I'll remember that for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use:

```
df.unstack().rename('Value').reset_index()

#df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
#df.T.reset_index().melt('Date').sort_values('Date')

#Output

#         Date      City  Value
#0  2019-12-20    Madrid     12
#1  2019-12-20  Valencia     15
#2  2019-12-20   Sevilla     15
#3  2019-12-21    Madrid     15
#4  2019-12-21  Valencia     16
#5  2019-12-21   Sevilla     30
#6  2019-12-22    Madrid     12
#7  2019-12-22  Valencia     12
#8  2019-12-22   Sevilla     12
```

or

```
df.T.reset_index().melt('Date')
#         Date      City  value
#0  2019-12-20    Madrid     12
#1  2019-12-21    Madrid     15
#2  2019-12-22    Madrid     12
#3  2019-12-20  Valencia     15
#4  2019-12-21  Valencia     16
#5  2019-12-22  Valencia     12
#6  2019-12-20   Sevilla     15
#7  2019-12-21   Sevilla     30
#8  2019-12-22   Sevilla     12
```